# C String manipulation: How do I append = (equal sign) to the beginning and end of a tokenized string, Wrong output due to newline upon pressing enter

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I'm currently having trouble with appending an equal sign, before and after my string is split into tokens. It leads me to the conclusion that I must replace the newline character at some point with my desired equal sign after splitting my string. I've tried looking at the c string.h library reference to see whether or not there is a way to replace the newline char using strstr to see whether or not there was already an "\n" in the tokenized string, but ran into an infinite loop when I tried that. I also thought about trying to replace the newline character, which should be the string length minus 1, and I admit, I have low familiarity in C. If you could take a look at my code, and provide some feedback, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time. I will admit I have low familiarity with C, but am currently reading the reference libraries.

```
// main method
int main(void){

// allocate memory
char string[256];
char *tokenizedString;
const char delimit[2] = " ";
const char *terminate = "\n";
do{
    // prompt user for a string we will tokenize
    do{
        printf("Enter no more than 65 tokens:\n");
        fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);

        // verify input length
        if(strlen(string) > 65 || strlen(string) <= 0) {
            printf("Invalid input. Please try again\n"); }
    } while(strlen(string) > 65);

    // tokenize the string
    tokenizedString = strtok(string, delimit);
    while(tokenizedString != NULL){
        printf("=%s=\n", tokenizedString);
        tokenizedString = strtok(NULL, delimit);
    }
    // replace newline character implicitly made by enter, it seems to be adding my newline character at the end of output
} while(strcmp(string, "\n"));

return 0;
}// end of method main
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter no more than most 65 tokens:
i am very tired sadface
=i=
=am=
=very=
=tired=
=sadface
=
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Enter no more than 65 tokens:
i am very tired sadface
=i=
=am=
=very=
=tired=
=sadface=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `strlen()`, you can do this instead

```
size_t length = strlen(string);
// Check that `length > 0'
string[length - 1] = '\0';
```

Advantages:

1. This way you would call `strlen()` only once. Calling it multiple times for the same string is inefficient anyway.
2. You always remove the trailing `'\n'` from the input string to your tokenization will work as expected.

Note: `strlen()` would never return a value *< 0*, because what it does is count the number of characters in the string, which is only 0 for `""` and *> 0* otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two ways to do it, the simplest is to add a `\n` to the token delimiter string

```
const char delimit[] = " \n";
```

(you don't need to use an array size if you are going to initialize a string array with a string literal)

so it eliminates the final `\n` that comes in with your input.  Another way is to search for it on reading and eliminate it from the input string.  You can use `strtok(3)` for this purpose also:

```
tokenizedString = strtok(string, "\n");
tokenizedString = strtok(tokenizedString, delimit);
```

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I have solved the problem! Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the case of the selected answer (the one marked with a tick) it's right that that procedure is good to eliminate the final `\n` from the string, but as it's stated there, you get advantage of having already called `strlen(3)` which is time consuming (as it searches the string for the final `\0`)  The initial approach from my answer doesn't require a two pass algorithm over the string and everithing resolves with only one pass.  And you can get a string not finished in `\n` also.